# error al insertar un valor double en una base de datos

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, double

intento hacer un insert de un valor double a una base de datos(MySQL)
y me muestra el error:
java.sql.SQLException: '∞' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value

```
Connection conexion = AdminConexion.getInstancia().obtenerConexion();
        PreparedStatement pstm = conexion.prepareStatement("insert into Lista( NombreLista, Agasajado, Monto a Recaudar por Participante, Monto Recaudado, Monto a Recaudar, Fecha Inicio, Fecha Fin, Mail Agasajado, Administrador, FechaAgasajo ) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        pstm.setString(1, lista.getNombreLista());
        pstm.setString(2, lista.getAgasajado());
        pstm.setDouble(3, lista.getMontoARecaudarPorParticipante());
        pstm.setDouble(4, lista.getMontoRecaudado());
        pstm.setDouble(5, lista.getMontoARecaudar());
        pstm.setString(6, lista.getFechaInicio());
        pstm.setString(7, lista.getFechaFin());
        pstm.setDouble(8, lista.getMontoRecaudado());
        pstm.setInt(9, lista.getAdministrador().getCodigo());
        pstm.setString(10, lista.getFechaAgasajo());
        pstm.execute();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Uno o más de los valores que intentas ingresar no es realmente un `Double`. El mensaje de error dice que es infinito, seguramente debido a que no estás recogiendo bien el dato o no lo estás parseando bien o algo. **¿Los getter que usas están haciendo bien su trabajo?** Me temo que no y deberías revisarlos y decirles que te devuelvan los valores correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

La declaración de campos no coincide con la asignación de valores.

asignas pstm.setDouble(8, lista.getMontoRecaudado()); dónde se esperaba, Mail Agasajado que muy posíblemente debiera ser string.

No veo claro por qué razón el error señale `'∞' is not a valid numeric or approximate numeric value` a no ser que se dispare porque no espera setDouble con param 8.
Si no es ese el problema al menos vas a resolver el de asignación que se observa en el código.
Espero sirva.